# Launch configuration references non-existing project

Tags: eclipse, maven

```
Launch configuration TestPanel references non-existing project NLDoc.
```

I installed latest Eclipse on Ubuntu, and import a Maven project. Building the project is fine. However, when in Eclipse I click "Run as->TestPanel", I received the above error.

I did some search and tried the following solution:

```
Project properties -> run/debug settings -> New -> Java Application
```

And then select my project name, and the main class, but it still not solving the project.

What could be other causes? I am using Oracle JDK8

EDIT:

Unfortunately, this is not a duplication, since i import my project as a Maven project, so it's already a Java project. Also, when I click "project properties" and followed the steps, I also verified it's a Java project.

So, it seems a similar problem but different causes.And this is exactly what I am asking. Hopefully somebody else encountered the same issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse -- Testng references non-existing project XXX, launch configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23116556/eclipse-testng-references-non-existing-project-xxx-launch-configuration)

Comment: It's a similar issue, but due to different causes. I did a lot of searches and tried suggested, but didn't work. BTW, my project is imported as a Maven project.

Comment: Look in the 'Project References' page of the project Properties

Comment: I have 4 projects with some dependencies, and I was trying to run one of them. In 'Project References', it displays the other 3 projects, which seems right.

Comment: I came across your question in review queue. I no longer uses eclipse so I cannot provide much help. But from your question I seems can't extract much useful information. Even with my limited experience with eclipse, I have encountered similiar issue with 3 different cause, ranging from broken maven plugins to accidental `grep xxx -r .`. Guessing and listing them all would not be a pleasant experience, not something efficient either. Perhaps a screenshot on your launch configurations would help those more experienced (than me) to answer your specific problem?